# QGIS - Import CSV column names as numbers

Tags: qgis, csv

I want to import a CSV table (no geometry) to QGIS. The column names which are numbers (e.g. 2004) are not getting imported.

This is my test CSV file:

```
Name;Eigenschaft;2004;test
derName;1;21;21
sdfsfaf;11;11;15
```

This is how it looks in QGIS:

[image: in QGIS]

The third column is not called `2004` like I want but `field_3`

How to solve this?

Comment: Sometimes it's common to see numbers preceded by an underscore if numbers are required for field names. E.g. `_2004`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field names starting with a number are not allowed in SQL and many formats, see

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917064/table-or-column-name-cannot-start-with-numeric

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/defense-mapping/creating-a-configuration-file-for-renaming-shapefile-fields.htm